# Can anyone help me figure out what this tool is? (autocomplete shape)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools

I think I remember watching an illustrator tutorial where the person used a tool that allowed them to draw a shape, and then illustrator would guess what kind of shape they were trying to draw and generate a perfect version of that shape. Ex: you sketch a fast version of a circle and then illustrator guesses from the sketch that you were trying to draw a circle, and changes the sketch into a perfect circle shape. Does anyone know what this is? Is it real or did I just dream this? lol

Answer (score 1):

if am not wrong you are talking about shape tool (shift+N).

it does exactly what you described.

Comment: Thank you!! So i'm not crazy!

Comment: no you are not crazy :D its one of the most least used tool.